# XContentType is removed from elasticSearch ver 7.17.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

upgraded elasticsearch to 7.17.3 and I encountered error `Cannot resolve symbol 'XContentType'`

Is 'XContentType' deprecated? What are its alternative?

Comment: You need to provide more context. What code are you executing?

Comment: code is in java springboot, previous version of elasticsearch have it

Comment: Which version of ES did you have before?

Comment: this is already ok, just import the class, it was changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'XContentType. JSON' has been replaced by 'XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()'

Answer (score 12):

The import path changed:

`import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType`

`import org.elasticsearch.xcontent.XContentType`